# Draw Image in a loop

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been doing a project and I'm wondering if how to loop the draw image for the whole background part? I have a tile set image of 48 x 63 only, then my canvas is 800 x 500. I can't loop on every point, I tried to but it didn't work so I did on my old stuff was..

```
 var x = document.getElementById('canvas_back');
        canvas = x.getContext('2d');

        var img = document.getElementById('grass');

        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;

        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, dy);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 60);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 120);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 180);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 240);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 300);
        canvas.drawImage(img, dx, 360);
        dx = dx + 48;
```

HTML

```
<canvas id = "canvas_back" height= "400px" width= "624px"> 
        <img id = 'grass' alt='Missing image' src = "Images/grass.png"/>
        <canvas id = "canvas_front" height= "400px" width= "600px">

            <img id = 'house' alt='Missing image' src = "Images/house3.png"/>
            <img id = 'mail' alt='Missing image' src = "Images/mail3.png"/>
            <img id = 'building' alt='Missing image' src = "Images/building2.png" />

            <img id = 'grass_up' alt = 'Missing image' src = "Images/grass_up.png"/>
            <img id = 'van' alt = 'Missing image' src = "Images/van2.png" />
            <img id = 'tree' alt = 'Missing image' src = "Images/tree.png" />
            <img id = 'player' alt = 'Missing image' src = "Images/player.png" />
        </canvas>
```

And so on.... Any easy loops to do it?

Comment: for loop? Google "JavaScript for loop"?

Comment: Tried to do a for loop but it didn't work on me. Didn't draw the images.

Comment: add your HTML please

Comment: does the code you provide work ? place in a JSFiddle and we'll alter it

Comment: @user3323654 Than you did it wrong, show us what you tried.

Comment: I did this for loop. for (int i = 60; i <= 360; i+=60){
    canvas.drawImage(img, dx, i)
   }
   dx = dx + 48;

Comment: Change `int` to `var`.

Comment: I'm very sorry! Haha i'm not really used to in javascript it works now lol thanks